# How to retrieve recursive childs on TypeORM

Tags: sql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've been experiencing some troubles lately trying to figure out a way to load recursively the childs of an entity on TypeORM (v0.3.10 on the moment I asked this question).

Right now, my objective is finding recursively all the childs from a given `parentId` (itself included).
For example:

| Id | ParentId |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | NULL |

- Calling `ID=1` should return `[1, 2, 3]`, since the ID itself shall be included, 2 is child of 1 and 3 is child of 2.
- Calling `ID=2` should return `[2, 3]`, since the ID itself shall be included and 3 is child of 2.

The entity itself looks like this at the moment:

```js
@Entity(TableNamesConstants.GROUPS)
export class Group {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => Group, { nullable: true })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'parentId' })
  parent?: Group;
  @Column('int', { nullable: true })
  parentId?: number;
}
```

I've tried several ways ([Tree entities](https://typeorm.io/tree-entities), trying to translate it from SQL to a TypeORM query following others suggestions, etc.) to no luck to achieve a N-depth query.

Can I have some guidance regarding this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Tree entities is your answer but you must make sure:

1. To put the Tree() decorator under the Entity() decorator above your Entity declaration.
2. use getTreeRepository() insted of getRepository().
3. TreeParent() and TreeChildren instead of regular Relation declaration.
   These were the mistakes I was making that might come of use to you.